# How to make a zip including submodules with Github actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to deploy to AWS using Github actions. The only problem is, that I have a `main repo` and `frontend and backend submodules` inside it.

This is the script I am using for deploy:

```
name: Deploy

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout source code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Generate deployment package
        run: git submodule update --init --recursive
        run: zip -r deploy.zip . -x '*.git*'

      - name: Get timestamp
        uses: gerred/actions/current-time@master
        id: current-time
        
      - name: Run string replace
        uses: frabert/replace-string-action@master
        id: format-time
        with:
          pattern: '[:\.]+'
          string: "${{ steps.current-time.outputs.time }}"
          replace-with: '-'
          flags: 'g'

      - name: Deploy to EB
        uses: einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v18
        with:
          aws_access_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws_secret_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_KEY }}
          application_name: test-stage
          environment_name: Testenv-env
          version_label: "${{ steps.format-time.outputs.replaced }}"
          region: eu-center-1
          deployment_package: deploy.zip
```

The problem is while it is creating a zip. It does not include submodules. Without submodules the project almost contains nothing. Is it possible somehow  to iclude them? Or do you have any better solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consulting [the `actions/checkout` documentation](https://github.com/actions/checkout#readme), there is a `submodules` argument (default value `false`) that controls whether the checkout includes submodules. So, you likely want

```yaml
steps:
  - name: Checkout source code
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      submodules: true
```